# GDAL 1.10 ogr2ogr OSM "Unable to open datasource"

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

I have a problem with ogr2ogr and osm file.

I install from source (on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS) newest GDAL libary and OGR still can't read osm files.

```
gdal-config --version
1.10.0
ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 1.10.0, released 2013/04/24
ogrinfo
Supported Formats:
  -> "ESRI Shapefile" (read/write)
  -> "MapInfo File" (read/write)
  -> "UK .NTF" (readonly)
  -> "SDTS" (readonly)
  -> "TIGER" (read/write)
  -> "S57" (read/write)
  -> "DGN" (read/write)
  -> "VRT" (readonly)
  -> "REC" (readonly)
  -> "Memory" (read/write)
  -> "BNA" (read/write)
  -> "CSV" (read/write)
  -> "GML" (read/write)
  -> "GPX" (read/write)
  -> "KML" (read/write)
  -> "GeoJSON" (read/write)
  -> "GMT" (read/write)
  -> "PostgreSQL" (read/write)
  -> "PCIDSK" (read/write)
  -> "XPlane" (readonly)
  -> "AVCBin" (readonly)
  -> "AVCE00" (readonly)
  -> "DXF" (read/write)
  -> "Geoconcept" (read/write)
  -> "GeoRSS" (read/write)
  -> "GPSTrackMaker" (read/write)
  -> "PGDump" (read/write)
  -> "GPSBabel" (read/write)
  -> "SUA" (readonly)
  -> "OpenAir" (readonly)
  -> "PDS" (readonly)
  -> "HTF" (readonly)
  -> "AeronavFAA" (readonly)
  -> "EDIGEO" (readonly)
  -> "SVG" (readonly)
  -> "Idrisi" (readonly)
  -> "ARCGEN" (readonly)
  -> "SEGUKOOA" (readonly)
  -> "SEGY" (readonly)
  -> "ODS" (read/write)
  -> "XLSX" (read/write)
  -> "PDF" (read/write)
```

When I try this:

```
ogrinfo UMP-PL-CCBySA_20130717.osm
```

and I get this:

```
ERROR 0:
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `UMP-PL-CCBySA_20130717.osm' with the following drivers.
Supported Formats:
  -> "ESRI Shapefile" (read/write)
...
...
```

Anyone know what I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Start with a clean copy of the svn source code repo:
$ svn co http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal

$ cd gdal

# Run configure and check its output, which should say something like:
$ ./configure
...
...
  Expat support:             yes
...
  SQLite support:            yes
...

# If it doesn't, check config.log to locate the problem(s) 
# and consult ./configure --help on how to fix them

# Once you configured correctly, run
$ make

# Then check the supported formats with
$ ./apps/ogrinfo --formats 

# Eventually, you run
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: It's working. Only one thing I do diffrent now, before I get source from http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/1.10.0/gdal-1.10.0.tar.gz
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm. For me, both options work. In any case: once you are already building from source, it is best to work with the code from the source code repo. I've been doing this for years now.

Comment: Are you sure this still works? I fail first line with `Could not read status line: connection was closed by server (http://svn.osgeo.org)`

Comment: Works for me:`$ svn co http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal`
`A    gdal/m4`
`A    gdal/m4/lib-link.m4`
`...`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already, you need to configure like this:

```
$ ./configure --with-spatialite=yes --with-sqlite3 (...)
```

If things work fine, you will end up with this line in the list of supported vector formats:

```
  -> "OSM" (readonly)
```

Comment: Do I need to uninstall this first? Effect of 
`./configure --with-spatialite=yes --with-sqlite3`
is
`SQLite support: yes` `SpatiaLite support:  yes` but in results of `ogrinfo --formats` (of course after `make` and `sudo make install`) I dont have `-> "OSM" (readonly)`

Comment: you should run `make clean` before running `make; make install`

Comment: it looks like I forgot to mention that you also need the configure option: `--with-expat=yes`

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work. Maybe you can tell me how to do this from beginning, so I can find where I make mistake.

Comment: OK. I will provide some more instructions in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html):

> needs libsqlite3 (and libexpat for OSM XML)

OSM isn't included by default.

Comment: Thanks but I have newest versions of packets `libsqlite3-0` and `libexpat1`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment, and some hours of my debugging my process, may I suggest that the Driver Error may be due to a corrupt source file.

[ogr2ogr missing drivers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199198/ogr2ogr-missing-drivers#comment302028_199198)

Please check with a sample source file with the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions : not having read right on the source (i.e. `whatever.osm`) file would also lead to the same error.  This can happen easily e.g. when you downloaded the file with your usual user then switch to a tab where another user is logged in (randomly : `postgres`…).