# How to open OSM file in Python with GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to open a *.osm file in Python with GDAL. But I doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
import ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('OSM')
datasource = driver.Open('map.osm')
layer = datasource.GetLayer()
```

Error looks like this

```
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../osm_reader.py", line 3, in <module>
    datasource = driver.Open('map.osm')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Open'
```

I exported the data directly from the OSM Website. 
My Python Version is 2.7.5.

About my GDAL Version I am not sure. And this might be the problem.

Easy Install says

```
U:\>easy_install GDAL
Searching for GDAL
Best match: GDAL 1.10.1
Adding GDAL 1.10.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

GDAL Version says

```
>>> gdal.VersionInfo()
'1810'
```

Does `1810` mean GDAL 1.10.1? How do I get this to work?

Comment: You tried opening it simply with `ogr.Open(...)` ?

Comment: `>>> print ogr.Open('map.osm') >>>
None`. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Well, it works for me, therefore i conclude that there could be only 2 reasons for your problem. (1) You're pointing to a non-existing path (2) your ogr bindings don't support osm files.

Comment: You have seen this posting? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67371/gdal-1-10-ogr2ogr-osm-unable-to-open-datasource

Comment: Yeah, I saw the other posting. I do have SQLite and Expat. What do you get for ogr.Open(...)?

Comment: And do you know what `1810` stands for? Does it stand for version 1.8.1?

Comment: I get an ogr object. Yes. Try compiling the osgeo libs from the source. Otherwise OSM is not going to work (most precompiled debs come without osm support)

Comment: So I tried it on a my Mac (where I know 1.10 works) and there it works. So there it seems like I have 1.10 and 1.8 GDAL installed and it chooses the 1.8.

Comment: osmconf.ini........ thats it..... I literally learnt how to compile gdal from source with expat and sqlite(spatialite) support only to come here and find out that it was missing osmconf.ini at the time... thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> gdal.VersionInfo()
'1810'
```

This means indeed that the GDAL version Python is using is GDAL 1.8. 
So I re-installed GDAL for Python with this [installation](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal).

After that the GDAL version was up to date (1.10.1).

```
>>> gdal.VersionInfo()
'1100100'
```

---

Though now I got a new error:

```
>>> print ogr.Open('map.osm')
Warning 1: Cannot find osmconf.ini configuration file
ERROR 1: Could not parse configuration file for OSM import
None
```

After copying the `osmconf.ini` into my working directory it finally worked.

```
>>> print ogr.Open('map.osm')
<osgeo.ogr.DataSource; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRDataSourceShadow *' at
0x02275518> >
```