# Convert OSM to Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap

How can I convert an OSM file to Shapefile? Is there a good tool or a good web page.

I tried this link https://code.google.com/archive/p/osm2shp/, but there is an error.

Comment: It would help if you described the error perhaps?

Comment: Please let us know the error and we will help if we can.

Comment: The code.google.com system is no longer supported by google so I suspect the code on there is out of date even if you can still download it. The `ogr2ogr` utility can convert .osm to .shp (and to even better formats, like GeoPackage). Try using that.

Comment: Thank you ver much . First App said to download .Net Framework 3.5 to work then i tried to install it and i get this Fehlercode: 0x800F081F

Comment: Thanks you very much Spacedman. How can i use this utility  ist this .exe program? or can one use it  with command line

Answer (score 11):

If you install the GDAL and OGR tools (open source, available for all major operating systems, see osgeo.org for downloads and details) you can do this on a command line:

```
$ ogr2ogr maps map.osm
```

and it will extract the OSM file into an existing folder called "maps" as several shapefiles. Note that OSM layers can contain more than one geometry type, but shapefiles can't, so you might see:

```
ERROR 6: Geometry type of `Geometry Collection' not supported in shapefiles.  Type can be overridden with a layer creation option of SHPT=POINT/ARC/POLYGON/MULTIPOINT/POINTZ/ARCZ/POLYGONZ/MULTIPOINTZ/MULTIPATCH.
```

Better to save to a GeoPackage, which can handle Geometry Collection and long field names (another source of shapefile errors):

```
$ ogr2ogr -f GPKG map.gpkg map.osm
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

now you have a GeoPackage file that contains all the layers which can be read in most major GIS packages.

Comment: Spacedman. Can you please more help i installed this tool and then i wrote in command line (Windows 10)                                      C:\Programme\gdal>ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" outputdir "C:\Users\alo\Desktop\London.osm" but i get message error ( ERROR 1: Could not parse configuration file for OSM import
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `C:\Users\alo\Desktop\London.osm' with the following drivers...
 

 what shoul i do

Comment: If you are having trouble at the command line I'd recommend installing QGIS and the Quick OSM plugin which has a tool for importing from an OSM file. Your problem seems to be that ogr2ogr can't find a configuration file that it needs: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75048/how-to-open-osm-file-in-python-with-gdal

Comment: Thnkas very much it worked ogr2ogr -f GPKG map.gpkg "C:\Users\alo\Desktop\London.osm"

Comment: Maybe you can find some more hints in https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles as a page in the OSM wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Use an online tool on the following website: https://export.hotosm.org