# ogr2ogr missing drivers

Tags: installation, ogr2ogr

I have a problem here with installing ogr ..
I followed this very usefull tutorial for installing ogr on Windows systems: http://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows
It seemed to work, because I can call ogr from commandline afterwards.

```
C:\Users\root>gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25
```

But when I try to use ogr2ogr it says that it can't find the drivers.
I'm on this for hours now but can't get it to work.
How do I register the drivers? The path is set correctly and I tried like thousands of different installations. All on a clean Virtual Machine which I reset after every failed installation ..

Please help me, I'm desperate :D

Edit:
This is the result I get when typing set g:

```
C:\Users\root>set G
GDAL_DATA=C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins
```

Which exactly matches my installation ..

Edit2:
When I'm trying to convert:

```
C:\Users\root>ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "C:\Users\root\Desktop\Plugin\Shapefiles_Karte\Bundeslaender\Bundeslaender.geojson" "C:\Users\root\Desktop\Plugin\Shapefiles_Karte\Bundeslaender\Bundeslaender.shp" -overwrite
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `C:\Users\root\Desktop\Plugin\Shapefiles_Karte\Bundeslaender\Bundeslaender.shp' with the following drivers.
  -> netCDF
  -> PCIDSK
  -> JP2OpenJPEG
  -> DB2ODBC
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> OGR_SDTS
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> OGR_VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> LIBKML
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> OGR_GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> ODBC
  -> WAsP
  -> PGeo
  -> MSSQLSpatial
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> MySQL
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDUMP
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> OGR_PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> Geomedia
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Cloudant
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> Walk
  -> CartoDB
  -> SXF
  -> Selafin
  -> JML
  -> PLSCENES
  -> CSW
  -> VDV
  -> TIGER
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> HTTP
```

Comment: Have you set the GDAL environment variables? https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#WhatisGDAL_DATAenvironmentvariable to match your installation... not just copy what's on the forms.

Comment: I sure did. I'm playing with thos paths for hours now ..
GDAL_DATA
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH
and the PATH of course. It matches the installation and gdal itself seems to be installed correctly .. but when I'm trying to use the drivers it can't find them ..

Comment: How are you trying to use them? I see a command line, try typing **set G** and insert what is returned into your question.

Comment: added above .. it matches correctly

Comment: Try unsetting your GDAL_DRIVER_PATH, in more recent versions I've found its' more hassle than it's worth. How long is your path? did you add GDAL to the end? I have also noticed that having GDAL too far down the path string can make it *not found*, try set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL;%PATH% and see if that helps. I also go to great lengths to ensure that GDAL isn't installed to c:\program files... the space in the path can potentially cause problems, try installing to c:\GDAL_XXbit (where XX is either 32 or 64).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Does your shapefile exist on the path given? The shapefile driver is installed and working... -f "geojson" shouldn't have quotes, it's -f geojson. None of those paths need quotes, there's not spaces in the path name but that shouldn't matter - best to get into the practice of having them there just in case. Does your VM have read/write permission to that folder?

Comment: Ok so I tried with and without the GDAL_DRIVER_PATH and the other path command you suggested but still the same. I also installed to C:\Gdal and set the path(s) correctly, but still the same. I really don't get it ..
I'm trying to convert a shapefile to geojson as an example. The shapefile exists and is vaild. The path is correct. The exact same command works on my work computer. I definitly need to check the installation at work out ..

Comment: From what I can see everything is valid, there's no reason (except for corrupt shapefile) that this wont work.. Esri Shapefile and GeoJSON drivers are both available... can you open the shapefile with QGIS and/or OGRINFO? Are all the required files there or is it just the .shp?

Comment: Oh no .. I could really cry right know :/ :D
It seems that the shapefile has somehow got corrupted during all my tries ..
I replaced it with a security copy I made and know it's working just fine ..
That's something the developers could have cleared out in the error response of the program, instead of saying that the driver failed :D
Now it's working! Thank you very much for all your help!! :)

Comment: You're welcome. I know how frustrating it can be when it *should* work but doesn't... All good now. Just remember the developers of GDAL weren't remunerated for their effort so good/descriptive error messages would be only if they felt like it - that's part of the fun of open source.

Comment: Is your OS 64 bit or 32 Bit? Is the GDAL you installed 32Bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Much of GDAL dev was remunerated, but under the terms agreed released under MIT. It is nonsense to say that it's "because open source". The message is clear, anywho imo, use ogrinfo to check assumptions about source files.

Comment: @Leo.1906 Did you get to the bottom of this? I have the same issue and have also followed the same setup guide. I have set the environment variables correctly but all my drivers won't work and just return "Unable to open datasource `PostgreSQL' with the following drivers."

Comment: Hmm it's been a long time. I figured out that a PostGIS installation does a good job on setting all those environment variables. But that's all I remember about that.