# Convert .osm to .shp file with .NET

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, convert

I am looking for some free dotNET libraries which can be used to convert an OpenStreet .osm file to .shp shapefile.

I did Google, but mostly found either [.exe files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/localosmtoshp/?source=typ_redirect), or [non.NET files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osm2shpjava/).

Can you point me to the .NET libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Shapefiles#Create_your_own_shapefiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Create_your_own_shapefiles) there is at least one of the various osm2shp softwares written in C#, the [osm2shp hosted at google code](http://code.google.com/p/osm2shp/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply @scai.
When trying to run the main .exe file, I am getting the same error message as reported in here: ```https://code.google.com/archive/p/osm2shp/issues/8```. Also when I try to open an .osm file by calling the ```OSM2SHP.osm.ReadFromFile``` method an error message appears: ```osm - Unknown attribute : copyright```.
It may be that the code is too old (written in 2008 for dotNET 2.0).

Comment: Do you know whether I can directly download the ```shp``` file from OpenStreet data? There is a webpage which explains how to download the ```osm``` file from OpenStreet data: ```http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data```. This is why I thought I can convert it. But if I could directly download the ```shp``` file, then I do not even need the osm2shp dotNET libraries. By the way, I do not want to use geofabrik.de as it does not allow download of the openstreet data by extent through url address, which is what I need.

Comment: It's called OpenStreetMap, not OpenStreet. OpenStreetMap doesn't offer shape files directly. However according to the wiki page already mentioned in my answer there are various third-party providers for shapefiles. Note that each of them might do different post-processings so the resulting shape files can be different.

Comment: Thank you for the correction @scai.
I need dotNET libraries, not a desktop application nor a website. The link you provided contains two dotNET libraries: ```osm2shp``` and ```GDAL/OGR```. The first one having upper issues. With the GDAL/OGR I had the famous "missing drivers issue" even though the version is newer than 1.10.0: ```http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67371/gdal-1-10-ogr2ogr-osm-unable-to-open-datasource```.